# User defined field not updating with PHP code

Tags: users, ubercart

I am using the uc_node_checkout and I need to set some fields that I have created. The php code is this

```
if (isset($order)) {
  foreach ($order->products as $product) {
    if (isset($product->data['node_checkout_nid'])) {
      $node = node_load($product->data['node_checkout_nid']);
      $node->field_productid['0']['value'] = $order->order_id;
      node_save($node);
    }
  }
}
```

If I create an order and add this line to the end of the php code, it dies and show a number.
die($node->field_productid['0']['value']);
When I remove that line and place and order the productid is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
<?php
      $node->field_productid['0']['value'] = $order->order_id;
?>
```

To this:

```
<?php
      $node->field_productid[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $order->order_id;
?>
```

See if that helps.